# If T under $\|\cdot\|_1$ continuous $\Rightarrow$ $T$ under $\|\cdot\|_2$ continuous, show that $\|\cdot\|_1$ is weaker than $\|\cdot\|_2$.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I am taking functional analysis course and encountering this problem:

*$X$ is a linear space with norm $\|\cdot\|_1$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$. If every continuous functional $T$ under $\|\cdot\|_1$ is continuous under $\|\cdot\|_2$, prove that $\|\cdot\|_1$ is weaker than $\|\cdot\|_2$, i.e., there exists $c>0$, s.t. $\|x\|_1\leqslant c\|\cdot\|_2, \forall x\in X$.*

I find it is easy to prove the converse: if $\|x\|_1\leqslant c\|x\|_2,\forall x$, then
$$\sup_{x\ne 0}\frac{|Tx|}{\|x\|_2}\leqslant \sup_{x\ne 0}\frac{c|Tx|}{\|x\|_1}\leqslant c\|T\|(\textrm{w.r.t.} \|\cdot\|_1)<\infty,$$
thus $T$ is continuous under $\|\cdot\|_2$.

However, the original direction of proof seems to be non-trivial. Could any one hint me what theorem or method should be taken? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(x_n)$ be bounded in $\|.\|_2$. If $f$ is a continuous linear functional on $(X,\|.||_1)$ then it  is a continuous linear functional on $(X,\|.||_2)$. This implies that $(f(x_n))$ is bounded. Since this is true for all continuous linear functionals $f$ on $(X,\|.||_1)$ it follows that $(x_n)$ is weakly bounded, hence norm bounded in $(X,\|.||_1)$ (as a consequence of Uniform Boundedness Principle). Hence, the result.

Comment: Nice solution (+)